# Circumcentre of Triangle Formed by Tangents of Intersecting Circles at the point of intersection

Tags: geometry, circles

I faced the above question in my textbook-

**Two circles with centres O and Q intersect at two points, one being A. Their tangents at A meet the circles again at B and C respectively. A point P is constructed such that AOPQ is a parallelogram. Prove that P is the circumcentre of triangle ABC.**

The method to solve this question is fairly simple. You apply the theorem that tangents are perpendicular to radius at point of contact, and then that the point P lies on the perpendicular bisectors of two sides of the triangle.

For context here's a formal proof-
https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/let-a-be-one-point-of-intersection-of-two-intersecting/

However, when I drew the diagram of this question, often P was in the exterior of triangle ABC or on it. For reference, here's the diagram given along with the question in the textbook :

[image]

That being said, ***what is the condition for P being within the triangle ABC?*** This is my question. Does this condition relate to the circles, as in, can we provide a condition including the radii of the circles, and the distance between the lens of the intersection? Note that any condition without some of these terms also works.

**EDIT:-**

From a discussion in the comments, P will lie on BC if the circles were orthogonal. We know that by the Pythagorean theorem, two circles of radii r_1 and r_2 whose centers are a distance d apart are orthogonal if

***r_1^2+r_2^2=d^2.***

So what you have to essentially find out is-

1. Threshold cases is the other two angles are acute.
2. How to exactly express this in the required terms.
3. If that's not possible, then why?

Comment: At one threshold between "inside" and "outside", $P$ lies on line $BC$. What can you say about this case?

Comment: True. Perhaps a special condition would stand for this case as well.

Comment: The condition for $P$ to lie on line $BC$ is indeed special. Figure out what that condition is, and how breaking it one way or the other causes $P$ to move inside or outside of $\triangle ABC$.

Comment: Hmm. Wouldn't the condition for that be that the circles are orthogonal.

Comment: *"Wouldn't the condition for that be that the circles are orthogonal."* Correct. Point $P$ will lie on line $BC$ if (and only if) the angle at $A$ is right —by [Thales' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27s_theorem)— which makes the circles orthogonal.

Comment: Alright. We already know that _P_ lies outside if the triangle is obtuse. How do we proceed further? How do you prove this given a certain prerequisite? One way you could go about this is proving that (either)  _∠OAC_ or/and _∠QOB_ has to be obtuse, i.e. surpass their tangents, but I cannot get further than that. However, I did notice that the magnitude of both these angles would be inversely proportional to the radii of the circles and the diameter of the intersection lens.

Comment: To summarize ... We can say that circumcenter $P$ lies on the same side of $BC$ as $A$ when $|OA|^2+|QA|^2>|OQ|^2$ (which happens for acute $\angle OAQ$). So, having $P$ lie within $\triangle ABC$'s interior requires at least this condition. ... Now, $P$ would still drift out of the interior if the angle at $B$ or $C$ were non-acute. I actually haven't given this situation much thought, although a quick sketch suggests that the geometry for the threshold case (with a right angle) might be interesting.

Comment: True, but I still wonder if this condition could be expressed in terms of the radii's and intersection distance.